How to compare multiple cells string and integer data with columns using python
I have an excel with some data(combination of string and integer) like below image enter image description here. If you compare column A and column B WITH column D and E(A1,B1 present in D and E and A3,B3 present in D,E...) so these two will true and other is false, how to write code in python I can see only row comparison, now looking for cell to column comparison like(A1,B1 has to compare column D,E and repeat this by increasing A2, A3.....
Sample Excel Data:  enter image description here
Comparison between excel multiple cells data(irrespective with data type) with multiple columns without knowing cells limit.

data = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35],
    'City': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


To compare string data across columns, you can use vectorized
operations. For example....:

df['Is_Alice'] = df['Name'] == 'Alice'

For integers, you can also use vectorized operations:

#Check if age is greater than 30

df['Over_30'] = df['Age'] > 30


compare data across different columns, you can do something like this:

df['Specific_Criteria'] = (df['Age'] > 30) & (df['City'] == 'Chicago')


You can compare filtered columns names in lists col1 and col2 with left join with indicator=True parameter in DataFrame.merge and compare helper column _merge:
cols1 = ['A','B']
cols2 = ['D','E']
df['C'] = df[cols1].merge(df[cols2], how='left', 
                          left_on=cols1, 
                          right_on=cols2, indicator=True)['_merge'].eq('both')

Or use Index.isin with convert columns to MultiIndex:
cols1 = ['A','B']
cols2 = ['D','E']
df['C'] = df.set_index(cols1).index.isin(df.set_index(cols2).index)

